# How can I replace some column values depending on a condition?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix `A` such that

```
A=
     4.0000  120.0000   92.0000         0         0   37.6000    0.1910   30.0000
    10.0000  168.0000   74.0000         0         0   38.0000    0.5370   34.0000
    10.0000  139.0000   80.0000         0         0   27.1000    1.4410   57.0000
     1.0000  139.0000   60.0000   23.0000  846.0000   30.1000    0.3980   59.0000
     5.0000  136.0000   72.0000   19.0000  175.0000   25.8000    0.5870   51.0000
     7.0000  121.0000         0         0         0   30.0000    0.4840   32.0000
```

I want to do two things:

1. Replace the values of the first column that are greater than 5 by 0.
2. In the second column, if the values are within the range 121-130, replace them by 0. If they are within the range 131-140, replace by 1, 141-150 by 2, 151-160 by 3, etc.

So the desired result matrix would be:

```
A=
    4.0000   0.0000   92.0000         0         0   37.6000    0.1910   30.0000
    0.0000   4.0000   74.0000         0         0   38.0000    0.5370   34.0000
    0.0000   1.0000   80.0000         0         0   27.1000    1.4410   57.0000
    1.0000   1.0000   60.0000   23.0000  846.0000   30.1000    0.3980   59.0000
    5.0000   1.0000   72.0000   19.0000  175.0000   25.8000    0.5870   51.0000
    0.0000   0.0000         0         0         0   30.0000    0.4840   32.0000
```

How can I accomplish this?

I was trying something like this:

```
counter=1;
for i = 1: rows
    if A(i,1) > 5
        A(i ,1) = 0;
    end
    if A(i,2) > 120 &&  A(i,2) < 130
        A(i ,2) = 0;
    end
    counter = counter+1;
end
```

Would using a case do the trick?

Comment: What about an edge value like 130? Would that be 0 or 1?

Comment: well forgot to say, an edge would be 0, 131-140 would be 1, 141-150 2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can modify the first 2 columns of `A` like so:

```
A(A(:,1) > 5,1) = 0;             %# Set values in column 1 greater than 5 to 0
A(:,2) = fix((A(:,2)-121)./10);  %# If the values in column 2 are all 120 or
                                 %#   greater you can shift, scale, then round
                                 %#   them towards 0 to get the new values
```

The above uses [matrix indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html) and [vectorized operations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html) to avoid for loops or case statements.

Comment: How is that working, could you explain, Fix rounds the number...but?

Comment: +1 for clever use of FIX. If the ranges are not equally spaced as above, you probably would use HISTC

Comment: @darkcminor: The function [FIX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fix.html) is equivalent to [FLOOR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/floor.html) for positive numbers and [CEIL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ceil.html) for negative numbers, so everything is rounded towards zero. If you want to get a better idea of what is done to each element of the second column when you subtract 121 and scale by 10, look at what you get before applying FIX: `(A(:,2)-121)./10`